# what may undesireably stop a long running PHP script?

Tags: php

If a long running php script is created in a LAMP stack, using:

```
set_time_limit(0);
header("Connection: close");
ignore_user_abort(true); // just to be safe
ob_start();

$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();
flush();            
session_write_close();

//Some long running code here
```

In what ways could this script subsequently be terminated externally (to the script itself)?

Comment: `kill -9 pid_of_script`. `shutdown`, `reboot`. exceeding cpu time limits, exceeding process limits external to php, blah blah blah. should we go on?

Comment: @MarcB - Can you make that an answer so that I can accept? I would also like to post a few comments to your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major reasons why your example script would end unexpectedly or undesireably are:

- `reboot` and `shutdown` - this should be ovious.
- memory limits of PHP, of Apache, or running out of memory on OS level will kill this script.
- in some setups, there might be limits for used CPU cycles, too.
- any PHP fatal error that occurs during runtime.
- `kill <pid>` with almost any signal (not only `kill -9`) will terminate the script.
- If the script is running inside `apache` using `mod_php`, then apache restarts would also kill the script.
  *Note that each long running script inside apache blocks a worker thread/process, which might be bad for your server performance. This* ***may*** *not apply in a `php-fcgi` environment!*

**To prevent *some* of this:**

- Run the script outside the apache environment. 
  I prefer calling `echo '/usr/bin/php myscript.php'| at now`. (using `at` scheduler, see manpage)
  `at` totally detaches your script from apache, so it will still run when the apache process ends.
- set the PHP memory limit to a high value or infinite. (anything > 512M is generally a bad idea)
  This can be done inside the script.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a bash script, that are running for too long and execute it using a cronjob.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script will kill process which running more than X hours
# egrep: the selected process; grep: hours
PIDS="`ps eaxo bsdtime,pid,comm | egrep "spamd|exim|mysqld|httpd" | grep " 1:" | awk '{print $2}'`"

# Kill the process
echo "Killing spamd, exim, mysqld and httpd processes running more than one hour..."
for i in ${PIDS}; do { echo "Killing $i"; kill -9 $i; }; done;
```

http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=26179

Comment: I guess the OP asked for reasons why the script could die unexpectedly / undesireably - not for a way how to kill it.

Comment: Why would someone kill mysqld/httpd :O

Comment: If you need to kill mysqld or httpd manually, you have something fundamentally wrong on your system.

Comment: `kill -9` on mysql is generally not very clever. especially, when using MyISAM / no binary logging / or when safe writes are disabled in InnoDB. In most cases it results in a broken database (only during writes, though)

Comment: That's just an example, you can easily remove the daemons you don't want to kill...

Comment: There is no reason you would ever want to kill these processes simply because they have been running for over an hour (unless, perhaps, your goal is to cause downtime). Having these processes running is normal on a server. They are supposed to stay running.